# Clicking on link removes the application name from URL, and moves back

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a Website `www.xyz.com` hosted on IIS.
I have created few child applications within same website.

So, my url becomes `www.xyz.com/app1`, now on `aap1` home page I have below link, which opens the page on same `app1`

```
<a href="Masters/Index">Index</a>
```

**But when I click on the link, It removes application name (i.e., `app1`) from URL and browse like below**

`www.xyz.com/Masters/Index` and I end up with `resource not found` error.

Whereas it should be `www.xyz.com/app1/Masters/Index`

I tried link with `../`, `/`, `./` prefix for link but none of them seems to work. I'm a missing something?

Please help.

Comment: Are `Masters` and `app1` in the same directory level? That would explain this issue.

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path? `<a href="http://yoursite.com/app1/Masters/Index">Index</a>`

Comment: yes, it does work then

Comment: where does this take you? `<a href="/Masters/Index">Index</a>`

Comment: This takes me to `www.xyz.com/Masters/Index` and removes `app1` from url

Comment: Bizarre. This (`<a href="Masters/Index">Index</a>`) should definitely work assuming you're in `app1` and `Masters` is truly a subdirectory. My only other thought is that you might have some htaccess redirect or something else that's affecting this. Can you link to a file in a different subdirectory (at the same level as `Masters`) as a test?

Comment: Happens for every other directory :( works fine if i use `<a href="app1/Masters/Index">Index</a>`

Comment: In that case, I'm going with the issue being some redirect set in htaccess or somewhere else on your server or DNS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your `app1` use an `Html.ActionLink` helper instead fo the hardcoded link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Masters", "Index")
```

This should keep the existing routing of the current web application.

[**LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String%29)

You can also use `@Url.Action` instead if you prefer to just update the url within your mark-up:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Masters", "Index")">Index</a>
```

Comment: Yes, This is an option, but this won't work in case of ajax request.. There i have syntax like `url: 'Masters/AddChangeMasterData',`

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh How are you building up the urls for the ajax calls? You can user `@Url.Action` from within a razor file and it will work the same.

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh If you use [@Url.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) helper, you can get the URL without the HTML tags. It's useful for embedding in JavaScript or directly into an `<a href=''>` element.

Comment: Omg, I didn't know that, Certainly helpful. Thanks & cheers !!

Comment: Can you please update the answer to add `@Url.Action`

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh Sure, no probs. I will add it when I get back on a PC. 

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh That is added now. :)